# Debugging user defined functions in XPath 3.0/Saxon

Tags: debugging, xpath, saxon

Is there any support for debugging xpath user-defined functions in the latest Saxon PE? I've used the trace function, but it seems to work in some contexts and not in others. I'm sure there's a logic to that, but I don't understand it. I'm really looking for something simple like something akin to `<xsl:message>`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your calls on trace() are working, but the output is confusing because of lazy evaluation, which means that things are often evaluated in a different order from what you expect. In fact, the optimizer can sometimes rearrange the expressions you write in your source into something quite different.

Have you tried the debuggers in tools like Stylus Studio or oXygen? Typically these disable some optimizations, making the sequence of execution more comprehensible.

Comment: My problem is that oXygen, which I have, doesn't support xpath 3.0. I was hoping to find something that would help me debug "inline functions" I guess I wasn't clear enough about that. I guess I'll try to play with simpler forms of my functions. See if that works and then put them back together.

Comment: So, the solution was not to stop using trace, but to use it everywhere. The more you use it, the more the pieces fit together and you can understand what's happening. The more I use xpath, the more it made sense to impl it using lazy evaluation. I just never thought it was. Silly me.